# Spin animation initiated on hover but still completes when off hover

Tags: css, animation, hover, transform

So I have completed some simple code to spin the inside element when you hover on the container.

This works just as I want it when the mouse is hovering over the container but when the mouse is no longer within the container the spin stops.

How can I complete a full spin rotation, initiated by a mouse hover where it will complete a full spin even if the mouse leaves the container, preferably with just CSS.

Current code:

HTML

```css
@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  25% { transform: rotate(-90deg); }
  50%{ transform: rotate(-180deg); }
  75% { transform: rotate(-270deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(-360deg); }
}

.logo:hover > .spin{ 
  animation: spin 450ms;
}

.logo{
  background: #eee;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 110px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="#">
  <div class="logo">
    <i class="fa fa-globe fa-2x spin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work ! :)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".logo").hover(function(){
   var logo = jQuery(this);
  if(!logo.hasClass('hover')){
     logo.addClass('hover');
     setTimeout(function(){
        logo.removeClass('hover');
     }, 450);
  }
}, function(){});
});
```

```css
@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  25% { transform: rotate(-90deg); }
  50%{ transform: rotate(-180deg); }
  75% { transform: rotate(-270deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(-360deg); }
}

.logo.hover > .spin{ 
  animation: spin 450ms;
}

.logo{
  background: #eee;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  li
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="#">
  <div class="logo">
    <i class="fa fa-globe fa-2x spin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: This works! I do wish there was some sort of css option though. Thanks!

Comment: No problem ! Glad I could help :)